# Is the hyphen necessary in "artificial-intelligence system?"

Tags: grammar

Is the hyphen necessary in "artificial-intelligence system," and if not, what is the rule of grammar that makes it unnecessary? I know that a hyphen is necessary for two-word adjectives, but artificial intelligence is an attributive noun in this context, so I don't think this rule applies here.

Comment: Is a hyphen necessary in *ice cream sandwich*? If there is no chance of confusion, then you can safely omit it. Whether you should or not is up to whatever particular style you want to use. (By the way, people do also write *ice-cream sandwich*.)

Comment: If it's for a university essay, consult the "house-style" guide that they publish for this sort of thing.